# MQException 2046 error when getting messages from MQ queue

Tags: java, mq, getmessage

I am trying to get the messages from one local queue. 
I have initialized the queue manager , local queue from which I am supposed to fetch the messages .

Open Input options used for local queue

```
int openInputOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT ;               
 MQQueue outputQueue=queueManager.accessQueue(remoteQueue, openInputOptions);
```

and get message options is

```
MQGetMessageOptions gmo=new MQGetMessageOptions();
gmo.options=MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;
gmo.matchOptions=MQC.MQMO_NONE;
```

When I execute this I am getting

**com.ibm.mq.MQException: Completion Code 2, Reason 2036 error .**

Which states **MQRC_NOT_OPEN_FOR_BROWSE**

So I tried  to use the below open option ,

```
int openInputOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_BROWSE;
```

When I try with this , it gives me error code 
**Completion code 2, Reason 2046 error .**

Comment: This is not Twitter. Write your titles in English, not hashtags.

Answer (score 0):

Is the queue actually local to the queue manager or are you trying to open a 'Remote Queue'.  Because if it was a 'Local Queue' then the 'MQC.MQOO_BROWSE' option would work.